# Future perfect/simple future/present perfect

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses, future-perfect, will-future

Please consider the following:
*They will report to me what they **will have known**/**will know**/**have known***. Which one is right if the context is **they will report to me after they know it**

Comment: "know" seems wrong here in any case.

Comment: *know* is not among the options

Comment: I mean that using the verb "to know" sounds weird to me, regardless of tense, and it seems weird in the explanatory sentence "they will report to me after they know it."  I would use "learn" or "find out," since "report" seems to imply that they are going to acquire some knowledge and then tell me about it.  This is also implied by "after they know it."  If they already have the knowledge, then I would use "tell" rather than "report."

Comment: Imagine the speaker is a commander in chief who has just ordered his men to find out something. These men have not got the knowledge, but they will. They are asked to report to the commander when they do.

Comment: @phoog however, thanks for your kind attention and response :)

Comment: When I imagine that the speaker is a commander, etc., as you suggest, then I imagine the phrase "they will report what they find out," or "they will report what they learn," or, perhaps more "official" sounding, "they will report their findings."  As I said, using "to know" in this context does not seem idiomatic.  I guess you could come up with a context in which "know" makes sense.  For example, "after they have learned X, they will report what they know, and we will proceed accordingly."  As you can see, this example agrees with DW256's answer.  But it also sounds a bit contrived.

Comment: If you say so. Thanks anyway, @phoog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause *what they know* is a relative clause. In integrated relative clauses, a simple present can be used for a future situation (CaGEL p135).

The natural interpretation, then, of:

> They will report to me what they know

would be that whatever they report to me, they will know when reporting it (Which is quite obvious if we think about it).

All of the other choices you've listed *will know* /  *have known* / *will have known* would not sound natural and give a strange interpretation.

*will know* - This would imply that they'll report of the things they will find out about after the future instance of reporting you are referring to.

*have known* - this would imply that they found out some piece of information and subsequently forgot it before reporting it, but do remember that they did know it.

*will have known* - same problem

In fact, I'd just replace the the *what* with a *when* and be done with it:

> They will report to me when they know

Comment: What about British English? Someone using British English once told me that I should always use a future tense in this case, even if it's an integrated relative clause, considering that the instance of knowing has not happened.

Comment: That would go against the way every native English speaker actually uses the language. The reference I have cited, in fact, has as its principal authors two British linguists.

Comment: I see. Then, either I misunderstood her or she misunderstood me. Thanks a lot, DW.